# How to customise header template in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, phtml, header, luma-theme, customize

Here is what i have already done.

- Installed Magento 2
- Created custom theme in magento 2
- Applied that theme
- Created "templates directories" to override template files

I have copied `header.phtml`

from `my-magento-directory\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html`

and pasted it to `my-magento-directory\app\design\frontend\my-package\my-theme\Magento_Theme\templates\html`

**I have this default luma theme header, please see the image below.**

[image]

**And i want to make it like this, please see the image below.**

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have it, just customize the code you have paisted into my-magento-directory\app\design\frontend\my-package\my-theme\Magento_Theme\templates\html and refresh the cache

Comment: But is it not actually customizing the entire header, that's what the problem is. See when I put some testing code into `header.phtml`, it comes into source I can see it in view source in the browser, but is only coming under `<ul class="header links">` only. It is not affecting the code outside of this `ul`. Please see the image I have added as edit in the question.

Comment: That template is nested within a parent template which contains the opening ul tag. Have you tried turning on template path hints to see exactly all of the templates which form the header. Also you should really be looking at using magento's layout.xml to make structural/layout changes.